# Calculate Quantiles on Groupby Dataframe and add value back to DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What I'm looking to do is group my Dataframe on a Categorical column, compute quantiles using second column, and store the result in a 3rd column. For simplicity lets just do the P50. Example below:

Original DF:

```
Col1     Col2 
 A        2   
 B        4
 C        2
 A        6
 B        12
 C        10
```

Desired DF:

```
Col1     Col2    Col3_P50
 A        2         4
 B        4         8
 C        2         6 
 A        6         4
 B        12        8
 C        10        6
```

One easy way would be to create a small dataframe of each Category (A,B,C) and compute quantile and merge back to existing DF, but my actual dataset has 100s of category so this isn't an option. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `transform` with `quantile`

```
df['Col3_P50'] = df.groupby("Col1")['Col2'].transform('quantile',0.5)
print(df)
```

---

```
  Col1  Col2  Col3_P50
0    A     2         4
1    B     4         8
2    C     2         6
3    A     6         4
4    B    12         8
5    C    10         6
```

If you have multiple values, one way is creating a dictionary and set the keys as column names and values inside the groupby:

```
d = {'P_50':0.5,'P_90':0.9}
for k,v in d.items():
    df[k]=df.groupby("Col1")['Col2'].transform('quantile',v)
print(df)

 Col1  Col2  P_50  P_90
0    A     2     4   5.6
1    B     4     8  11.2
2    C     2     6   9.2
3    A     6     4   5.6
4    B    12     8  11.2
5    C    10     6   9.2
```

Comment: with this suggestion, if I wanted to also calculate the P90 as a column would I need to do so on a new line?

Comment: @dmd7 added another solution for multiple values